# Getting Run-Time Check Failure #0 when calling CButton::Create second time through loop. What is the problem?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

When running this code I'm getting a 'Run-Time Check Failure #0' in the second iteration at Create.

```
    m_nBtnCnt = List.GetCount();
    if (m_pButton = new CColorButton[m_nBtnCnt])
    {
        // create the buttons on the dialog bar
        for (int i = 0; i < m_nBtnCnt; i++)
        {
            // get the button def from the list
            BUTTONDEF Def;
            List.Get(i, (void *)&Def);
            // set up the window rectangle
            CRect Rect(Def.nLeft, Def.nTop + nOff, Def.nLeft + 80, Def.nTop + 50 + nOff);
            // set the window style
            DWORD dwStyle = BS_PUSHBUTTON | BS_MULTILINE | BS_OWNERDRAW | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE;
            // create the button window on the dialog bar
            m_pButton[i].Create(Def.szText, dwStyle, Rect, this, Def.nId);
            m_pButton[i].SetFont(pFont);
            m_pButton[i].SetColor(Def.crButton, Def.crText);
        }
    }
```

This same code exists in three applications but I only get the error in one, and then only when it's built in debug mode.  The code is in the OnCreate of the view class; no other executing threads exist at this point.  I'm using VS 2017 with MFC.  If the code is built in release mode it executes without error.  I'm quite confused about this; can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: What information did you get from debugging the issue?

Comment: Don't you have some code somewhere inside an `ASSERT(...)`? The code surrounded by the parenthesis is only executed in Debug mode.

Comment: Comment out `List.Get(i, (void *)&Def);` and tell us if the runtime error still occurs.

Comment: If I do that then I do not have the information required to create the button; there is no reason to execute the remainder of the code in the loop

Comment: @Jabberwocky OK, I commented out the List.Get(i, (void *)&Def).  I got a Runtime check error #3 at the rectangle creation.  The list code has been in use for over 20 years with no problems.  It really is well debugged.

Comment: @IInspectable None, really.  All of the data appears to be correct.  There does not appear to be any memory corruption.  What I have noticed is that the second time through the for loop the call to CButton::Create ends up in CWnd::DoDataExchange.  This is probably prompting the Runtime Error Check #0.  As mentioned befor this code executes correctly in two other applications.

Comment: @sergiol I do not.  I have included the entire OnCreate method for completeness.

Comment: Remove bits of code here and there posssibly replacing it with some stub code and see iof the problem goes away just in order to narrow down the problem. Put breakpoints, step through the code etc.

Comment: Also replace old fashioned C++ code like `foo = new Bar[n]` with modern C++ stuff such as `std::vector`. Replace old fashioned C type arrays such as `foo bar[n]` with `std::array` which has bounds checking in debug builds.

Comment: I suspect it has to do with CALLING CONVENTION. You may be including external stuff, like functions of an external DLL and not having specified the adequate Calling convention. Do you have more text of the error after the 'Run-Time Check Failure #0' ?

Comment: Sure, a mismatch in calling conventions will corrupt the stack, but trigger a different error diagnostic. This one is caused, most likely, by an out of bounds write. `(void *)&Def` has everything to make that a thing: An untyped pointer into stack space. If you to verify this, run the code under Application Verifier.

Comment: _Run-Time Check Failure #3_  is "variable used without initialisation". Instead of just commenting out `List.Get(i, (void *)&Def)` comment it out __and__ initialize `Def` with some hard code values.

Comment: @sergiol The complete error text is: Run-Time Check Failure #0 - The value of ESP was not properly saved across a function call.  This is usually a result of calling a function declared with one calling convention with a function pointer declared with a different calling convention.  And I agree that does point to a calling convention error.  And I would agree except that this EXACT SAME code is running without error in two other applications.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I commented out the List.Get() call and statically initialized the Def structure with reasonable values.  I got the same error the second time through the loop.  This was relatively quick; replacing the list and array structures will take a little longer.  I want to try IInspectable's suggestion of running under Application Verifier first.

Comment: Try to remove more elsewhere. Try 32 bit vs. 64 bit builds.

Comment: @IInspectable Ran the code under Application Verifier.  It ran to the fault; there was nothing logged in Application Verifier.  I only had Basics flagged in the Tests pane.  Is there any other testing you would suggest?

Comment: @Jabberwocky I removed everything except the code created by the environment and the required code to make the loop execute.  On the second iteration of the loop the call to Create threw the same exception.  We build 32-bit code because many of our clients as still using a 32-bit Windows 7 OS.

Comment: @Jabberwocky When I converted the array of buttons to a vector the problem went away, but there is still an issue when I delete the buttons on the vector (heap corruption), which was probably the initial problem all along.  I'll post again if I need advise on that.  Thank you everyone for your time and suggestions.

Comment: @CurtisConrad keep us informed, this kind of problem is always interesting

Comment: @Jabberwocky The application was using a CColorButton header from its local folder and code from another.  Evidently they did not match.  Removed the local header file and the heap corruption vanished.  Thanks again.